# What prevents someone from claiming to be the murderer in order to get the real murderer off?

Tags: united-states, murder, double-jeopardy

Say someone is on trial for a murder they committed. During the trial, one of the witnesses, a friend of the defendant, admits that it was actually they who were the killer. It seems that this would be enough to create reasonable doubt and get an acquittal, or even possibly have the state drop the charges because they now believe that they should be charging this other person.

After the trial ends, the friend presents irrefutable proof that they weren't actually the murderer. Of course, this friend could be charged with perjury, obstruction, etc... but the original defendant can't be re-tried for the murder because of double jeopardy, and their friend can't be tried (or won't be found guilty) because of the evidence that he didn't do it.

Is there a flaw in this system? Something that prevents someone from actually doing this?

Related: [Can someone get protection under Double Jeopardy for a crime by arranging to be put on trial with fake evidence that is then disproven?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22046/can-someone-get-protection-under-double-jeopardy-for-a-crime-by-arranging-to-be)

Side-note; something just like this happened in an episode of Law and Order; though I had been wondering about this long before seeing that.

Comment: Forget an episode of L&O, this happened in real life when a [US Marine was on trial](https://taskandpurpose.com/marine-says-eddie-gallagher-innocent) for killing an Iraqi prisoner.  Another marine from the same group claimed he was responsible for the death.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to give feedback so that the question could be improved? I'm new to this site.

Comment: Are we not entertaining the idea that both parties can be tried together for the murder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not as simple as the witness just making the assertion that they are the killer.
They will be subject to grueling cross examination to break their story.

- If the victim was killed at a specific time, perhaps the prosecution can prove the witness was somewhere else at that time, and therefore lying. *(No Opportunity)*
- If the victim was killed with a specific weapon, perhaps the prosecution can prove that only the accused had the weapon, and the witness had no access to it, and therefore lying. *(No Means)*
- If the victim was killed in a specific way, perhaps the witness doesn't know any of the details of how the crime happened, and therefore is not credible. *(No Knowledge)*
- If the accused's DNA is found at the scene, and their shirt is covered in blood, and the witness has no corroborating evidence against them, then the witness is likely lying. *(No Evidence)*
- If the witness claims he is the murderer, the prosecution can inquire as to *why* he killed the victim.  The real murderer had a reason: Perhaps money, power, hatred, passion, etc, that the witness may not be able to provide. *(No Motive)*

Planting doubt in the mind of a jury is an effective defense.  But lying about who did what, when, how, and why it is not as easy as you suggest.

Comment: Why could the witness not plead the fifth on everything?

Comment: How do you "plead the fifth" on evidence that the witness doesn't have access to a .45 revolver, while the accused does?  How do you plead the 5th on *not* having blood stains on your shirt, while the accused does?  On a credit-card receipt showing you were no where near the murder scene?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor You can only "plead the 5th" to avoid answering police questions or taking the stand at your own trial. If you are offering evidence for the defence then it *has* to be done on the witness stand or it doesn't count. Once on the stand you have to answer every question; you can't pick and chose.

Comment: @Paul Johnson I am pretty sure that a witness, particularly one under subpoena by either side, may invoke a fifth amendment right not to answer specific questions which might incriminate him or her, while answering ones which are not incriminating.   In fact, i think the witness can be (and often will be) required to answer questions which could not be incriminating, while not answering ones which might well be.

Comment: @Paul Johnson One called as a witness at the trial of another can (in the US) use the Fifth Amendment privilege to refuse to answer incriminating questions. It can also be used in Grand Jury proceedings, including by one who is not a target of the investigation.

Comment: @DavidSiegel wouldn't the witness have waived the fifth amendment right by testifying to the commission of the crime?  After that testimony, and because of the resulting waiver, couldn't the witness be compelled to answer other questions concerning the claimed commission of the crime?

Comment: @DavidSiegel If a witness does that, then the court will exclude their testimony. They can't provide testimony for one side in a trial and deny the other side the opportunity to demonstrate that the testimony is nonsense. Alternatively, the prosecution could just give them immunity. Then they have no reasonable fear of prosecution for a truthful answer and can be compelled to testify for both sides. They can still be prosecuted for perjury if they lie.

Comment: @David A witness can answer some questions and refuse to answer others, citing the 5th, provided that there is a legitimate concern that the answers might incriminate the witness.  The Judge may or may not exclude the testimony depending on the exact facts. A grant of immunity can indeed force the witness to testify, but the state is often reluctant to grant it. What questions might be incriminating depends on the facts. Paul J's idea that only a defendant can invoke the 5th is wrong. Also his statement that a witness cannot invoke the 5th selectively. In fact it must be done selectively.

Answer (score 8):

I think this sort of thing happens far more often in fiction than in real life. Off hand I recall a Perry Mason novel and a Donald Westlake novel which used versions of this plot. In the Parry mason the witness invoked the fifth Admendment, and only after having been granted immunity, was asked "Did you see the deceased that night" "Yes I saw him when I shot and killed him." Of course, being a Perry Mason novel, the real criminal was convicted in the end.

If this were attempted in actuality, it **might** be held that the Harry Aleman precedent applied, and that the accused had never been in jeopardy, and could therefore be retried (in the Harry Aleman case the judge was bribed).  I don't know of any actual case where this argument against Double Jeopardy has been made.

In any case the witness who claims to have committed the crime would surely be guilty of perjury, probably of obstruction of justice, and possibly would be held to be an accessory to the original crime. The witness and the original accused might be charged with conspiracy to commit the original crime, or with conspiracy to obstruct justice.

Besides that, all the possibilities described in the answer by user abelenky might be used to show the witness was lying during the trial, and thus to convict the original accused.

In short this would be a quite risky scheme for both the witness and the accused. To the best of my knowledge it has rarely been attempted in actuality.

Answer (score 1):

One scenario where this sometimes works is when a parent confesses to a crime to protect their child -- especially with father/son, it's tough to disprove with DNA.

During the trial is a little late, of course -- it's much more effective to confess early and make a plea bargain so that the matter never gets a court examination.

[False confessions are pretty damning even if the accused recants and claims that the confession was coerced](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-human-equation/201805/innocent-people-don-t-confess-and-they-don-t-plead-guilty); ([efforts to prevent interrogation tactics that often lead to false confessions are being strongly resisted by most police departments](http://www.law.northwestern.edu/legalclinic/wrongfulconvictions/issues/falseconfessions/)) and the chance of it being believed is presumably even stronger if the person confession has a strong motive to stick to their story.

I'm surprised that I can't find any newspaper stories about a parent who confessed to a murder later shown to have been committed by their child, but here's one about [a dad who confessed to abusing his kids (the "evidence" in this case was later shown to be the result of a birth defect) hoping that they would be returned to his wife.](https://amp.miamiherald.com/news/nation-world/national/article159231674.html)

Answer (score 0):

Believability.  If the Queen of England confesses to being the second shooter of JFK, the authorities are going to want rock solid proof.

In real life, if you confess on stand you’ll just be making a fool of yourself and helping to convict the person on trial.  If you confess off the stand, they are going to gather as much evidence to support your assertion as they can, just in case you decide to recant your confession.

One last straw, is that there’s no law saying you can’t arrest someone for the same thing twice, cases are often diminished with *nolle prosequi*, which can then end up back in court. And nothing says they can’t argue you both independently did it.  Charge both of you and let the jury sort it out.

It’s almost certainly happened that someone has taken the rap for someone else, but court room confessions where everyone gets away with it is not realistic.